# How to give a modules a different name than a crate

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a rather large library that I would like to split up into multiple smaller crates, but I still want to keep the same module names.

So lets say I have a library called `xyz`, and I want to split it up into the following crates:

- `xyz-core`
- `xyz-graphics`
- `xyz-audio`
- `xyz-input`

How can I make it so that the modules are still available like this:

- `xyz::core::*`
- `xyz::graphics::*`
- `xyz::audio::*`
- `xyz::input::*`

Instead of turning it into this:

- `xyz_core::*`
- `xyz_graphics::*`
- `xyz_audio::*`
- `xyz_input::*`

I'd also like to be able to refer to the crate contents using the `xyz::*` syntax from within the crates. So `xyz-graphics` can refer to `xyz-core` using `xyz::core::*` etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a main crate `xyz` that has those as dependencies, and re-export all items from the subcrates inside it:

```rust
pub mod core {
    #[doc(inline)]
    pub use xyz_core::*;
}
pub mod graphics {
    #[doc(inline)]
    pub use xyz_graphics::*;
}
pub mod audio {
    #[doc(inline)]
    pub use xyz_audio::*;
}
pub mod input {
    #[doc(inline)]
    pub use xyz_input::*;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this still require the crates themselves to reference each other with `xyz_core` etc?

Comment: @RickdeWater Yes.

Comment: Don't forget that `pub use foo as bar;` is also an option but, I don't know how this might effect `#[doc(inline)]`. Plus you can also use `extern crate foo as bar;` to rename an imported crate globally without re-exporting.

Comment: @Locke Yes but I avoided it because IIRC it does not work with `#[doc(inline)]`.

Comment: I figured it out! For external consumption I use your solution to create a "main" crate. Internally I rename the crates in `[dependencies]` like this: `graphics = { path = "../xyz-graphics", package = "xyz-graphics" }`